# Training a Custom Model using Java Code - Stanford NER

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, crf

Could someone help me to convert these lines to Java code, instead of using terminal?

I'm trying to train my own model using Stanford Ner:

```
java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBTokenizer jane-austen-emma-ch1.txt > jane-austen-emma-ch1.tok

perl -ne 'chomp; print "$_\tO\n"' jane-austen-emma-ch1.tok > jane-austen-emma-ch1.tsv

java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop austen.prop
```

And must the training file be in .tsv format???

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you show us some java code you've already written and where you're stuck? We're here to help you, not to replace you...

Comment: Yes. I'm just concerned with this line: java -cp stanford-ner.jar edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier -prop austen.prop

this is my code:
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(new FileInputStream(new File("austen.prop")));
        
        CRFClassifier crf = new CRFClassifier(prop);
        crf.train();

in the properties file: I have all parameters correct but Always I got this error:
deftab720=
Unknown property: |deftab720|
tf1ansiansicpg1252cocoartf1265cocoasubrtf210=
tf1ansiansicpg1252cocoartf1265cocoasubrtf210|

Comment: Please post the contents of the file `austen.prop`. It looks like it contains some bad property (which isn't in the `austen.prop` file published on the Stanford NER site).

Comment: trainFile = 45_N_22_E.tsv
serializeTo = mahmoud-model.ser.gz
map = msentencenum=0,word=1,mindex=2,mstart=3,mend=4,mlemma=5,answer=6

type=crf
useClassFeature=true
useWord=true

useSentenceNum=true
useIndex=true
useStart=false
useEnd=false
useLemma=true


This is the content of my properties file. Please note that I updated to classes : NERFeatureFactory.java , SeqClassifierFlags.java, AnnotationLookup.java, CoreAnnotations.java to fit with my specified properties above.

Comment: e.g. for the property "msentencenum=0"
I have the following line in SeqClassifierFlags.java:
Boolean useSentenceNum = false;
Also in the if-statement, it has a line.
For the class AnnotationType.java, I have the following:
MSENTENCENUM_KEY(CoreAnnotations.MSentenceNum.class, "msentencenum")
For the class CoreAnnotations.java, I have the following:
public static class MSentenceNum implements CoreAnnotations<Integer>{ public class<Integer> getType(){ return Integer.class;}}
For the class NERFeatureFactory.java :
if (flags.useSentenceNum){featuresCpC.add(c.get(MSentenceNum.class)+"-MSM");}